# How to use a bottom-border for underneath a word, limited length and centred?

Tags: javascript, css, html, containers

On [this](http://ryanteaches.com/gcsechemistry.html) page, at the bottom, I am trying to set the grey line under the copyright text to 30%, so it is shorter than the text. My problem, is that when set to a smaller % than the length of the text, it puts the text on 2 lines. I want the text on one line.

Copyright box code:

```html
.copyright-container{
 box-sizing: border-box;
padding-right:20px;padding-left:20px;
background-color: black;
text-align: center;
position:relative;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
height:220px;
    color: white;
}

.vert-align{
position: relative;
top: 50%;
}
.headline {
    width: 30%; 
    line-height: 1.5em;
    border-bottom:2px solid #6d6666;
    margin:0px auto; 
    color:white;
}
```

Other code:

```html
<div class="copyright-container">
  <div class="vert-align">
   <p class="headline">Copyright &copy; 2017 RyanTeaches - All Rights Reserved.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I'm new to html and css

many thanks, 
Ryan

Comment: You cannot achieve that using only the `border-bottom` rule. The border always spans the whole element it is attached to. You could create a new element within the `<p class='headline'>` with 30% width, set `height` to `2px` and `background` to `gray`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pseudoelements:

```
.headline:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 43%;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 1px;
    width: 15%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #6d6666;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do it with a style property assigned to the text. However you can do it as illustrated below:

```css
.headline {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    margin: 0px auto;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
}

.headline_under {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    max-width: 120px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p class="headline">Copyright © 2017 RyanTeaches - All Rights Reserved.</p>
<div class="headline_under"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
.headline {
 
    line-height: 2.5em;
    margin:0px auto; 

}

.headline:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 40%;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 1px;
    width: 20%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #6d6666;
    color:white;
}
```

This combination sorted it for me! Thank you guys!

I want to insert this into every page, using just one line of code. I cant use php. Would I be able to use JS for this, if so, how would I write the JS?

Cheers!

Comment: No problem, glad to help. If you feel my answer solved this question please mark accordingly! If you want it inserted on every page you will need to use something like PHP.